# Redux-Saga Component Setup

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

I'm having trouble getting redux-saga to work.  I'm thinking the issue lies somewhere between the saga_component.js and saga_screen.js files.  It may be I'm not using the correct syntax to map out the API?

I'm getting eror: 
"undefined is not a function (near '...ConnectData.map' ".
This is located in the Saga_component.js file.

I've been working on this for a while now, not sure what to adjust at this point.  Would greatly appreciate some guidance.  This is a link to the repo. All screens and components can be found in the 'src' file.

App.js File

```
import React from "react";
import Setup from "./src/boot/setup";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './src/store';

export default class App extends React.Component {

 render() {
   return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <Setup/>
     </Provider>
    );
   }}
```

Store.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import AllReducers from '../src/reducers';
import rootSaga from '../src/saga'; 

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

const store = createStore(
 AllReducers,
 applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
 sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

 export default store;
```

saga.js

```
import { call, put, takeEvery, takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";

import { REQUEST_API_DATA, receiveApiData } from "./actions";
import { fetchData } from "./api"; 

function* getApiData(action) {
  try {
   // do api call
   const data = yield call(fetchData);
   yield put(receiveApiData(data));
  } catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
 }
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(REQUEST_API_DATA, getApiData);
}
```

data.js (this is the reducer)

```
import { RECEIVE_API_DATA } from "../actions";

export default (state = {}, { type, data }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case RECEIVE_API_DATA:
    return data;
    default:
     return state;
       }
     };
```

actionsCreators.js

```
 import { REQUEST_API_DATA, RECEIVE_API_DATA} from './types';

 export const requestApiData = () => { 
  return {
 type: REQUEST_API_DATA 
 }
};
export const receiveApiData = (data) => { 
  return {
  type: RECEIVE_API_DATA, 
   data 
 }
};
```

saga_component.js

```
import React from "react";
import { AppRegistry, View, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { Container, Body, Content, Header, Left, Right, Icon, Title, 
Input, Item, Label, Button, Text } from "native-base";


export default class SagaComponent extends React.Component {

renderList() {

const ConnectData = this.props.data; 

return ConnectData.map((data) => {
  return (

  <View  style={{width: 280}}> 
  <Text style={styles.TextLight}><Text style={styles.TextDark}>Dest City:</Text> {data.name}</Text>
  <Text style={styles.TextLight}><Text style={styles.TextDark}>ETA:</Text> {data.email}</Text>
  </View>
  );
```

});
}

```
render() {
  return (
  <View>
      <Label>Username</Label>

      {this.renderList()}
  </View>
  );
 }
}
```

saga_screen.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Text,  Button } from "native-base";
import {  View, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import styles from "../styles/styles";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { requestApiData } from "../actions";

import SagaComponent from '../components/saga_component';

class SagaScreen extends React.Component {


render() {
 return (
    <Container style={styles.container}>        
      <View style={{marginTop: 50 }}>
        <SagaComponent data={this.props.data}/>  
      </View> 

      <Button block style={styles.Home_btns}  
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}> 
        <Text>Home</Text> 
      </Button> 
    </Container>
  );
 }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
  data: state.data,
  };
 }

 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
 bindActionCreators({ requestApiData }, dispatch);


 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SagaScreen);
```

Api.js

```
export const fetchData = async () => {
try {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
};
```

index.js(reducer index.js file)

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import data from "./data";


const AllReducers = combineReducers({

data,  
});

export default AllReducers;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem could be in your reducer. Instead of returning `data` you should `return { data };`

Also, as an aside, you might want to guard against falsey data in your saga_component `(ConnectData || []).map((data) => {`

Comment: I'm still receiving this error message:   "undefined is not a function (near '...ConnectData.map' ". This is located in the Saga_component.js file

Comment: @AdamDonatelli can you post the stack trace and your updated Saga_component.js file?

Comment: This is a link to the stackTrace and saga_component.js 
https://jsfiddle.net/psychatelli/9d8z5cms/4/

Also, I should mention...  within the source tab of my console, when hovering over the parameters and imports: 
- 'RECEIVE_API_DATA'  
- 'data' 
in my data.js file, it says they are undefined.  

It also says undefined for for these within my saga.js file:  
- 'REQUEST_API_DATA', 
- 'receiveApiData',
- 'data'

Comment: Hmm. you're using destructing on your function arguments so I'd assume somewhere the `data` variable is undefined.  Try `(ConnectData || []).map((data) => {` in your saga_component and also, `yield put(receiveApiData((data || [])));` in your saga

Comment: Or even in your data.js you have to set default values for your reducer function `export default (state = {}, { type, data = [] }) => {`

Comment: Receiving pretty much the same error.  It says: Undefined is not a function near ConnectData || []}.map .  I've updated the other files as you mentioned.  Here is a link to the code https://jsfiddle.net/psychatelli/9d8z5cms/9/

Comment: In your saga, I just noticed that you're using the `call` effect on an async function.  According to the doc, you should probably wrap the async function with a normal function perhaps (https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/index.html#callfn-args) or convert that async function into a generator function.

Comment: oh and can you post the full stack trace w/ the error as well?  last time when you posted the stack trace in fiddle, i did not see in it the 'undefined is not a function' message.